# Thin GZIP decode on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gzip, thin

I'm using thin as a Rails server, and I want to send some JSON data gzipped, but in localhost it falls with MultiJson error (unknown symbols).

How can I enable gzip support for local thin using without nginx or apache?

Error text:

```
15:46:09 web.1     | Started PUT "/api/me" for 192.168.192.8 at 2011-11-25 15:46:09 +0600
15:46:09 web.1     | Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
15:46:09 web.1     | Contents:
15:46:09 web.1     | 
15:46:09 web.1     | 
15:46:09 web.1     | MultiJson::DecodeError (743: unexpected token at ''):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rack includes a middleware called `Rack::Deflater` which is what you want.

include `config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater` in your `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

As a rack middleware, I think Rack::Deflater it will work with other WebServers

If you are serving assets thru Rails, do this:

## config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Deflater
```

[Reference](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/content-compression-with-rack-deflater)